# Paypal + PHP subscription billing?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to bill users a subscription fee, and I want to track if the payment was successful. But this seems to be very complicated, I have setup the Paypal PHP SDK and the samples are working, but I am not sure how to proceed now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track recurring payments, you can use PayPal IPN feature. refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/?mark=IPN, PayPal will send IPN message to your IPN URL if any transaction occur.